# Matrix powering in PARI/GP

Tags: algorithm, linear-algebra, computation-theory, pari

Which algorithm is used for matrix powering in PARI/GP and what is its computational complexity? Is it repeated squaring algorithm (binary powering) or something else? I cannot find these informations on the internet.

**SOLVED**

According to Bill Allombert (main PARI/GP developer) it is a binary powering which has O(log n) computational complexity.

Comment: Maybe have a look at the source code? https://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/pub/pari/snapshots/

Comment: @JohanC Thank you for the link.

Comment: Instead of appending _Solved […]_ to the question, you can actually answer your own question below.